# mysql nodeJS result json format

Tags: json, node.js, node-mysql

mysql is returning me result as

```
    +-------------------+
    column_name
    +-------------------+
    result1
    result2
    +-------------------+
```

and I am getting result in json format is of this format

```
    [{"column_name":"result1"},{"column_name":"result2"}]
```

but I wanted it in json format like this (without using iteration logic)

```
    [{"column_name":["result1","result2"]}]
```

Is there any such nodejs mysql method available or json formation module  available???